# What is the highest value of pieces on this particular 6x6 board, without any of them attacking each other?

Tags: problems, point-value

I got a question in school in which I have to get the highest score possible by adding pieces on a 6x6 board like this:

[image]

The rules are that they are the same color and may never attack each other, and that pieces on my board must also be on yours in the same position.

Here are the point values:

Queen(D)15 points

Rook(R)15 points

Kings(K)10 points

Bishop(B)=9 points

Knight(H)=5 points

Pawn=0 points

My highest value was 97 by placing 8 bishops.

Comment: yes @RewanDemontay

Comment: Thanks if you could help @RewanDemontay

Comment: @RewanDemontay yes

Comment: @RewanDemontay everyone has the same question but with different pieces already placed, you also have to add the 'already placed' pieces in the endscore, my highest score was by 8 bisshops

Comment: Can the K D go anywhere or are those squares fixed?

Comment: @yobamamama they have to stay on the same position

Comment: @RewanDemontay yes, thanks, I have 5 try's to enter the answer for school, but every mistake = -10 points from max 50

Comment: @RewanDemontay do you think that 97 is the highest value?

Comment: I am a parent, so I have to ask: "Why are we doing your homework?"

Comment: @PhishMaster I am not a teacher, but personally I wouldn't allow it. But a user rated in meta told me homework is allowed in the site if it shows effort. The user here has provided a 97 score answer, meanning it has made an effort not just provided an ennunciate and asked for the solution. [Here a meta post that deals with it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This was the correct answer with 100 points!

Comment: Supertuper :) Thanks for sharing and welcome to chess stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a slightly higher value of **98** by replacing a bishop with a king.

[image]

You can create images of various board sizes like this at [Apronus.com](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?w=6&h=6).

Comment: okay, thanks, are you sure this is the heighest?

Comment: I got 98 with a different layout.  Do not guarantee there is not more if I kept playing with it.

Comment: @RewanDemontay I will try your answer tomorrow in school, thank you a lot!

Comment: @RewanDemontay yes but I am not sure if it is the right one, if it works I will accept!, thank you!

Comment: @RewanDemontay hi, sorry but your answer was wrong... ):

Comment: @Tijmen Meijer I took some time trying to beat Rewan score, but I desisted to try to beat a chess composer. Rewan and me would like to know wat's the higest possible score, so if you have it, please add your own answer with the solution please. Can you add using the editor of Apronus.com?

Comment: someone else came up with an idea for 100 points

Answer (score -1):

The max is 90 +Q + K  =  105 + K as  I understand the problem.  You can place six rooks at 15 each.

Then if you replace any of the rooks with a Q you lose two rooks by being attacked by that new queen.

I get 115 max as I *can* put six rooks on the board with the K and Q. 
And no piece is attacking any others.

Final answer:  115

4k3
7r
r7
2r5
5r2
6r1
1r6
3q4

Comment: @yobamamama sorry but this is not right I guess

Comment: Unless I put them on my diagram wrong they did not attack each other.  They did attack empty squares but not thepiece directly.   Now that I see the value of 10 for the King AND IF you can have more kings then I can get more than 105.

Comment: @yobamamama can you maybe sent a picture of how your board looks like? because I don't get how... and yes you can place everything as much as you can

Comment: see edit for layout.  to see it just fill in squares that are attacked. then see where you can put the rooks.  Cant replace R with 2B without being attacked by some piece. Ditto for enough horsies.

Comment: @yobamamama the board is 6x6 not 8x8